# How to build an Input field with restrictions

Tags: html, css, reactjs

Hello everyone I am a junior web dev. and I've been stuck on this task for weeks now :[]. I need an input field that will show default text coming from the backend. Restrictions I need for this input field are: The input line should break after reaching 30 characters and some parts of default text should be noneditable.

//Here's the closest solution that I came up

```js
import React, { useEffect } from "react";
import styles from "./TextEditor.module.css";

const TextEditor = (props) => {
  var limit = 80000; //height limit
  let defaultvalueArr = props.data.variables.map((vari, index) => {
    return vari.texts.map((p, index) => {
      return p;
    });
  });
  useEffect(() => {
    const box = document.getElementById(props.title);
    var charlimit = 30; // char limit per line
    var space;
    box.onkeyup = function () {
      var lines = box.value.split("\n");
      console.log(box.value, "box.value");
      for (var i = 0; i < lines.length; i++) {
        if (lines[i].length <= charlimit) continue;
        var j = 0;
        space = charlimit;
        while (j++ <= charlimit) {
          if (lines[i].charAt(j) === " ") space = j;
        }
        lines[i + 1] = lines[i].substring(space + 1) + (lines[i + 1] || "");
        lines[i] = lines[i].substring(0, space);
      }
      box.value = lines.slice(0, 500).join("\n");
    };
    box.oninput = function() {
      box.style.height = "";
      box.style.height = Math.min(box.scrollHeight, limit) + "px";
    };
    box.value = defaultvalueArr.join("\n");
  }, []);

  return (
    <div className={styles.TextEditor}>
      <textarea
        id={props.title}
        className={styles.TextArea}
        // rows={defaultvalueArr[0].length}
      ></textarea>
    </div>
  );
};

export default TextEditor;
```

[output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8mwbD.png)

the problem with this solution is that when the number of characters reaches 30 the cursor jumps at the end of text

Comment: can you show your implementation ?

Comment: Okey I will edit and add the closes "solution"